# SQL query returns entire table in stead of single row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax

After clicking on a div, ajax request is sent to PHP with a single param(id). But, in stead of one single row, I recieve an entire table.

regardless of using while loop, or placing LIMIT to query, I always get everything in table.

this is jquery:

```
$('.fa-expand').click(function() {

    var storyId = $(this)[0].id.split('_')[1];
    var data = {singleStoryInfoWithId: storyId};

    $.ajax({

        url: '../modules/feed.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {

            $('.newsModal').append(response);
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

this is PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['singleStoryInfoWithId'])) {

    getStoryWitId($_POST['singleStoryInfoWithId']);
};


function getStoryWitId ($id) {

    global $connectionFeed;

    $query = "SELECT story_title, story_date, story_content, story_cover FROM story WHERE story_id={$id}";

    $result = mysqli_query($connectionFeed, $query);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    $story_title = $row['story_title'];
    $story_content = $row['story_content'];

    echo "<h2>$story_title</h2>";
    echo "<h2>$story_content</h2>";
}
```

It does send the requested query but at the end of an entire table.

in my db I have 5 stories(first, second, third, etc.) and when I click on the third one for example, after sending ajax request, the response I get from the server is: first, second, third, fourth, fifth, third. The last one is the only one I need.

So what am I doing terribly wrong exactly?

thanks in advance guys!

Comment: In your HTML, do you have multiple items with class `'fa-expand'`?

Comment: For one, if `getStoryWitId()` is supposed to return a single row, you shouldn't fetch rows in a loop, you should just fetch one row. The query does look like it should only match one row, though, so that's weird.

Comment: `story_id` auto increments? This is open to SQL injections. Parameterize.

Comment: @WillardSolutions Yes, I do... but each one has unique id which is sent properly through  AJAX (var storyId = $(this)[0].id.split('_')[1];) and according to the network tab in mozilla, request is ok and the param is sent.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I tried without the loop... this is just the latest test, so to say... still puts it after all other rows like I explained at the last section of my question

Comment: `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))` ? You, yourself, are responsible for this. Why are you looping through all results? Update your SQL to use `LIMIT 1` or take the first result.

Comment: What sort of input checking are you doing to verify `$_POST['singleStoryInfoWithId']` has what you expect? Like a previous commenter suggested, you should be using a parameterized query for safety.

Comment: Looks like you are _append_ ing the result to something, so if "first, second third...etc" are already there...........

Comment: @Jaquarh I still get the same problem... without the loop was my first try. Still same result... I edited my question so that you can have a look... still comes at the bottom of all others

Comment: @DinoCoderSaurus Yes I am appending to modal which is an empty string. I also get the same response when checking in network tab (moz browser)

Comment: What does `var_dump($row)` give you? I suggest adding LIMIT 1 to your SQL query.

Comment: What does `print_r($result->num_rows)` give?

Comment: @Jaquarh var_dump gives > array(4) { ["story_title"]=> string(11) "Third Story" ["story_date"]=> string(10) "2018-11-03" ["story_content"]=> string(11) "Super stuff" ["story_cover"]=> string(9) "cover.jpg" }

Comment: @user3783243 print_r($result->num_rows) gives > 1

Comment: Is this online, or locally hosted? The results indicate you are only getting back the 1 row you are requesting.

Comment: @Jaquarh oh and I did put LIMIT 1 in the query... no solution

Comment: @user3783243 it's locally hosted with xampp

Comment: What does `console.log(response)` give you? Your PHP code is fine if it is returning only one row, maybe check what `response` holds and see if its your JS that is causing the issue

Comment: @Jaquarh I noticed that part of response I get is from another function in the same .php file. I don't know however why is it overlapping. other two functions work perfectly though

Comment: After your call to `getStoryWitId()` add `exit();` so it stops the code after it has given your desired output and doesn't continue to execute any other code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you never `exit()` once you have returned your desired output. Thus any instructions below this `if` expression will be executed and mix into your output.

In future, please create a minimal, **complete** and verifiable example so we could of seen this earlier.

```
if(isset($_POST['singleStoryInfoWithId'])) {    
    getStoryWitId($_POST['singleStoryInfoWithId']);
}

echo 'This will still get mixed in with the output';
```

After your call to `getStoryWitId()` you need to `exit()` so the program ignores any following instructions.

```
if(isset($_POST['singleStoryInfoWithId'])) {
    getStoryWitId($_POST['singleStoryInfoWithId']);
    exit();
}

echo 'This will no longer get mixed in with the output';
```

Comment: You're welcome, debugging your data comes in helpful. Consider using `console.log()` and `var_dump()` - it contains a lot of helpful information, or none at all ;) @AleksandarJocic